# Как на Руси называли альбиносов?

Tags: этимология

До того как "альбинос" пришло из португальского, как звали таких людей русским словом?

Comment: Каких "таких"? Белых негров?  А откуда они на Руси? Кстати, популярная версия заимствтования из португальского мне лично не очевидна. Корень общероманский.

Comment: @behemothus альбиносы - это люди, которые не вырабатывают меланин.  Альбинос имеет кожу нежно-розового оттенка, с просвечивающимися капиллярами, при этом волосы очень тонкие и мягкие с белым или желтоватым оттенком. Альбинизм встречается у всех человеческих рас, хотя понятно, что у европеоидов он не так заметен.

Comment: Марк Из, это я знаю. ))) А вот кому могло понадобиться на Руси как-то специально называть альбиносов, если даже португальцы использовали это слово как терминологический синоним "белому негру". Возможно, конечно, было название для зверюшек всяких альбиносов, но я как-то не вспоминаю вообще упоминаний о таких... А про людей - это по вашей части. Вы помните в обозримой истории хоть одно упоминание в источниках о чем-то таком - под любым названием? Понимаете, даже синонимов нет. Вообще. Кроме "белого негра" и ему подобных.

Comment: А, нк так вы же сами это и пишете в ответе. О чем тогда разговор))

Comment: @behemothus Дело то не в переводе слова. Как заметил МаркИз не только негры обладают заметными характеристиками, когда у человека альбинизм. Цвет радужки, волос, кожи; неспособность к загару и болезненная чувствительность к яркому свету. Может таких людей ведьмами и колдунами кличали. Не уверен, от чего и спрашиваю. P.s. Ну а слово само из латыни исходит (albus), но в русский оно были заимствовано не из латыни.

Comment: Ну заметил Марк Из - и что? Вопрос-то не в этом. А как на Руси картошку называли до Екатерины?  как называли голландцев, датчан, немцев? - всех немцами. Как кошки называют кошек? Как питекантропы называли девственниц? Нужды не было в специальном слове. Насчет "не из латыни" - это уже какие-то разговоры марсианские. А почему нет?

Comment: @behemothus Ну не расстраивайтесь вы так, что не знаете ответа... а вы сразу полемику разводите. То что не было нужды - это сугубо субъективно; вы же один не можете говорить за нужды целого народа, отделенного временем. Мож тут найдутся люди, читавшие исторические документы или изучавшие смежные вопросы. Ну а на счет этимологии, мне не ясно чему вы так не верите. Также как слово _канделябр_ заимствовано из французского, пускай и слово имеет латинские корни.

Comment: Спасибо, я постараюсь больше Вас не замечать.

Answer (score 3):

Никак не звали. В русском языке и для более распространённых оттенков волос используются замствованные слова (блондин, брюнет, шатен). Если говорить о названии цвета волос, то их могли называть просто *белыми*. Из слов, употреблявшихся только к волосам можно вспомнит *белобрысый* (буквально белобровый), правда, это не обязательно альбинос, может быть и просто светлый блондин. И *белёсый* (беловатый, тускло-белый). У С. А. Есенина есть строчки, описывающие себя:

> Блондинистый, почти белёсый,
>   В легендах ставший как туман...

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, самое точное слово - "белобрысый", поскольку в его этимологии есть указание на "брови", которые (вместе с волосами и ресницами) в рассматриваемом случае тоже светлые. Из множества приводимых синонимов, вероятно, такой же смысл когда-то имело "белоголовый". "Альбинос" - дипломатичный вариант "белобрысого" (этим словом в детстве дразнят).